# Vue semantic ui select styling issue

Tags: vue.js, semantic-ui

I have an issue with styling a select inside a v-for loop. Not really sure what’s causing this, it seems that the javascript specific to the dropdown is not executed.

basically student have evaluations and teachers can see those and are able to give a mark on an eval

for some reason the grade selects are not styled properly

Evalution.vue:

```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(evaluation, index) in evaluations">
            <div v-if="index == 0" class="ui divider"></div>
            <h3>{{ evaluation.subject.name }}</h3>
            <p>Passed on: {{ moment(evaluation.passed_at).format("DD-MM-YYYY") }}</p>

            <div v-show="evaluation.pivot.result !== null">
                Note: {{ evaluation.pivot.result + "/20" }}
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="ui blue button">Modify</button>
            </div>
            <div v-show="evaluation.pivot.result == null">
                <div class="ui sub header"></div>
                <select :id="'grade'+index" class="ui dropdown compact">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Grade</option>
                    <template v-for="grade in grades">
                        <option :value="grade.id">
                            {{ grade.text }}
                        </option>
                    </template>

                </select>
                <button class="ui tiny red button">Rate</button>
            </div>

            <p>Corrected by: {{ evaluation.teacher.firstname }} {{ evaluation.teacher.lastname }}</p>
            <div v-if="index !== evaluations.length-1" class="ui divider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

...

props: ['evaluations'],
data() {
            return {
                selectedGrade: '',
                grades: [
                    {text: "0", id: 0},
                    {text: "1", id: 1},
                    {text: "2", id: 2},
                    {text: "3", id: 3},
                    {text: "4", id: 4},
                    {text: "5", id: 5},
                    {text: "6", id: 6},
                    {text: "7", id: 7},
                    {text: "8", id: 8},
                    {text: "9", id: 9},
                    {text: "10", id: 10},
                    {text: "11", id: 11},
                    {text: "12", id: 12},
                    {text: "13", id: 13},
                    {text: "14", id: 14},
                    {text: "15", id: 15},
                    {text: "16", id: 16},
                    {text: "17", id: 17},
                    {text: "18", id: 18},
                    {text: "19", id: 19},
                    {text: "20", id: 20},

                ]
            }
```

```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: I would avoid using `dropdowns` in semantic when using `Vue`, they are difficult to deal with, because much of what they do requires jQuery to update the DOM, and correctly syncing the events is a nightmare. Instead I would go for a Vue specific select like [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select).

Comment: its the dropdown that are generated inside the v-for, they dont get the javascript that styles them, After the page is loaded i can apply $('#elem').dropdown() and it styles it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by adding:

```
Vue.directive('dropdown', {
    inserted(el) {
        $(el).dropdown()
    }
})
```

and add the directive on my select:

```
<select v-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

The downside of using a UI framework is that sometimes the styles are scoped for their own component so you can't override them. I don't see what you're asking here (javascript problem) but you keep mentioning about the styles.

In such cases, I create a wrapper `div` and write styles around it. If it doesn't seem to be possible, I dive into the Framework's styles then fix in it.

Another possibility is to use `!important` in your component for the style attribute you need to fix in the Framework.